# $\Bbb Z^\ast$ What is this notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does $\Bbb Z^\ast$ mean? I would think some subset of the integers but I cannot find a definition. Thank you.

Comment: [Mathworld has it](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Star.html)

Comment: I am helping my friend in Brazil prepare for an entrance examination for University.  She sent me a document that has some example problems, which I translated to English. There is no explanation of this notation in the document. I would think mathematical notation is universal, regardless of language. The original document is in Portuguese, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Use of similar notation in different ways among different fields of mathematics doesn't surprise me. What we probably need is some sense of the context in which that occurs: an abstract algebra problem? a number theory problem?

Comment: find the product of all the elements of the set A = {x is an element of Z* | x(3x-2)(2x-4)(-x-6)=0 }.  I arrive at two different answers based on two different responses given here. The first, Z* is all non-zero integers (I believe this is the correct interpretation of this notation) , gives -8. The second, Z* is all non-negative integers, give 0. Thank you all for your help

Comment: For an algebraist, $\mathbb Z^*$ would certainly be the set of invertible elements in the multiplicative monoid, i.e. $\{\pm1\}$, but that interpretation seems excluded by the context. Perhaps the notation is peculiar to the Brazilian educational system.

Answer (score 6):

@dwalke: This means all integers except for 0.

Edit: I'm all the more convinced now that you said it's a "vestibular"-type question.  This notation is taught in the standard high-school curriculum in Brazil.  See http://www.infoescola.com/matematica/numeros-inteiros/ for example.

Comment: This is not consistent with Semiclassical's comment above.

Comment: Mathworld has $\mathbb{Z}^+$ for positive integers and $\mathbb{Z}^-$ for negative integers. (Also, did you mean all _positive_ integers greater than 0?)

Answer (score 1):

I see there is some disagreement, but the notation $R^\ast$ or $R^\times$ with $R$ a commutative ring means the [group of units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) of $R$ to me. With this interpretation, we have $\Bbb Z^\ast = \{\pm1\}$.